# How to draw two series in the same chart that has different data time in xAxis

Tags: highcharts

I'll try to draw two different series in the same chart. I already did with the same data xAxis. But in my real case it couldn't be same.

For example
Temperature1
   data      [ 36 ,   37 ,  36   ,  45];
   categories[ 10 ,   11 ,  12   ,  13]
Temperature2
   data      [34   , 38   ,  35  ,  23 ];
   categories[10.5 , 11.3 , 12.5 , 13.7]

As you see the xAxis values are not the same for each series. 
I saw some solution like use two xAxis but it does not work for me. I need to make a draw with only one xAxis.

Any help about it.

```
<button id="btn">Redraw</button>
<script>
  jQuery('#btn').bind('click', function() {
    var chart1 = jQuery('#chart_1').highcharts();
    chart1.series[0].update({
      data: [ 36 ,   37 ,  36   ,  45];     
    }, false);
     chart1.series[1].update({
      data: [34   , 38   ,  35  ,  23 ]     
    }, false);
        chart1.xAxis[0].update({
      categories: [ 10 ,   11 ,  12   ,  13]      
    });
    chart1.redraw();
  });
```

Comment: Please have a look maybe it helps [2SeriesChart](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781783559688/1/ch01lvl1sec11/including-multiple-series-in-one-chart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Combine the data and category to a 2 Dimensional array.
2. Then sort the data based on categories in increasing order, the array should like:     [ [ 10, 36 ], [ 10.5, 34 ], [ 11, 37 ], [ 11.3, 38 ], [ 12, 36 ], [
   12.5, 35 ], [ 13, 45 ], [ 13.7, 23 ] ]
3. Use this as data in the chart, it will be populated as below:

```js
  $('#container').highcharts({

    series: [{
    type: 'line',
      data: [
        [10, 36],
        [10.5, 34],
        [11, 37],
        [11.3, 38],
        [12, 36],
        [12.5, 35],
        [13, 45],
        [13.7, 23]
      ]
    }]
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Example by Highcharts: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes/grid

Comment: Thanks Ashu. It was I was looking for.... To complement your information Im going to leave a link that I found today where everyone interested it could take a look how to draw if the X values are not the same for different series. Regards  http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/ddELH/

Answer (score 0):

Use `null` points:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'scatter'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['10', '10.5', '11', '11.3', '12', '12.5', '13', '13.7']
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Temperature (°C)'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Series1',
    data: [36, null, 37, null, 36, null, 45]
  }, {
    name: 'Series 2',
    data: [null, 34, null, 38, null, 35, null, 23]
  }]
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ag6x4sqt/